# Quick File Navigation for Open Workspace only

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started using the Quick File Navigation in VSCode, using Cmd+P.

It's really handy, but I am facing a problem. When I type a file name into the Quick File Navigation bar, it shows me files from my currently open workspace **and** previously opened workspaces.

How can I edit the option to make sure that the files **only** from my currently open workspace are shown?

Comment: Does disabling `Quick Open: Include History` fix the problem?  So that recently opened files from other workspaces aren't included?

Comment: @Mark Hi! How can I disable `Quick Open: Include History`?

Comment: Search for that in your Settings and uncheck it.

Comment: @Mark Ah! That did it! Thank you! :D

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't sure it would fix your problem but since it does I'll put it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the previously opened workspace was in the same window, it may be that those recently opened files are still included in your `History` of opened files in the Quick Open panel.  In other words vscode is saving your opened files to its history regardless of which workspace they were in.

So I suggest disabling

> **Search> Quick Open: Include History**
>
> Whether to include results from recently opened files in the file
>   results for Quick Open